# Is it possible to make things like buttons or text areas be part of the component code but then be omit when you want to use that component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I have this form component that I created but in some cases I want it to have a button and in other cases I want it to have a text field instead of the input field like I have coded.

```
function FormTypeOne(props) {
  return (
    <form className={classes.form}>
      <div className={classes.control}>
        <label htmlFor={"title"}>{props.title}</label>
        <input type={props.type} required id={props.id} />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Is it possible to add a button and a text field but then decide which one I want to use? Or do I need to make 3 different components?

Comment: It's really up to you and your use case please explain "but in some cases", so we could maybe recommend an approach for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can provide your conditions in props, then display the right button depending on the props received :

```
function FormTypeOne({case1, case2}) {
  return (
    <form className={classes.form}>
      <div className={classes.control}>
        <label htmlFor={"title"}>{props.title}</label>
        <input type={props.type} required id={props.id} />
        {case1 && <button />}
        {case2 && <label />}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

So if case1 = true, it will display the button and if case2 is true, it will display the label

For example :

```
function NewMeetupForm() {
  return (
    <Card>
      {' '}
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Title" />
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Image" htmlFor="image" type="url" id="image" case1 />
      <FormTypeOne title="Address" type="text" id="address" case2 />
    </Card>
  );
}
```

So you will have button on the second one and label on the third one

Comment: using logic directly inside `return` will cause performance issues

Comment: Using this example, how would I then call it in the following code?

`function NewMeetupForm() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Title" />
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Image" htmlFor="image" type="url" id="image" />
      <FormTypeOne title="Address" type="text" id="address" />
    </Card>
  )
}
`

Comment: function NewMeetupForm() {   return (     <Card>       <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Title" />       <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Image" htmlFor="image" type="url" id="image" case1 />       <FormTypeOne title="Address" type="text" id="address" case2 />     </Card>   ) }

Comment: Hagai Harari, yes you are right but I wanted to make it as simple as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can send a prop to decide what to show

```
function FormTypeOne(props) {
  const htmlElem = useMemo(() => props.isButton ?
              <button /> : 
              <input type={props.type} required id={props.id} />
, [props.isButton])

  return (
    <form className={classes.form}>
      <div className={classes.control}>
      <label htmlFor={"title"}>{props.title}</label>
      {htmlElem}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

in this example use a `boolean` prop `isButton`

Comment: Using this example, how would I then call it in the following code?

`function NewMeetupForm() {
  return (
    <Card>
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Title" />
      <FormTypeOne title="Meetup Image" htmlFor="image" type="url" id="image" />
      <FormTypeOne title="Address" type="text" id="address" />
    </Card>
  )
}
`